# Select columns and copy duplicates between them

Tags: excel, vba, macos, duplicates

Two nonadjacent columns, Column A and C, contain strings and Column E (again nonadjacent) should contain the duplicate strings between Column A and C.

Now my main problems is that Columns A and C are different lengths and the duplicates aren't per se on the same row.

When not using VBA, the following input Column E gives the solution except for the blanks.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C:$C,0)),"",A1)
```

For example:
**Column A**
potatoe
tomatoe
broccoli
pepper
mushroom

**Column C**
mushroom
cucumber
broccoli
salt
fennel

**Column E should be**
mushroom
broccoli

This is what I've been able to find so far, but it is very wrong. I just find myself unable to breakdown the issue.

```
Sub Duplicates()
  Dim duplicates As Range
  Set duplicates = Columns("A", "C")
  activesheet.duplicates.Copy Destination:=activesheet.Range("E1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Try this:

```
  Sub PopulateColE()

     Dim cl As Range
     Dim CurrentRow As Integer: CurrentRow = 1

     On Error Resume Next

     For Each cl In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("C:C"))
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Match cl.Value, Range("A:A"), 0

        If Err.Number = 0 Then
           Range("E" & CurrentRow).Value = cl.Value
           CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
        End If

        Err.Clear
     Next cl
  End Sub
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you! I'll try and actually understand what you did.. :-)

Comment: While we're at it (and if allowed here) another question. I run this code for columns A and C (giving E) and then I run it also for A and B (giving F). Is it possible to remove from column F, the duplicates with E?

Comment: EASIEST way (If I understand your question) - Add in an extra column between E & F, run the macro on those two columns, then delete out the old F

Comment: That makes sense, but I think that is exactly the opposite. If Column E is **abcde**, and Column F is **defgh**. Then I would F to be **fgh**, and I think your solution would give me **de**, no?

Comment: Again, a **QUICK** fix would be simply changing `If Err.Number = 0 Then` to `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` - I hope that makes sense...